# How can I force screen orientation on some layout where the layout have several versions? (Android Studio)

Tags: java, android

How can I force screen orientation on some layout where the layout  have several versions , I'm trying to lock portrait mode for normal screens(phones) while on the other hand I want landscape mode to be for tablet devices

## java answers if possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easiest way:

values-sw300.xml (or whatever other size definition you have of "tablet")

```
<bool name="isTablet">true</bool>
```

values.xml

```
<bool name="isTablet">false</bool>
```

main_activity.java

```
if(!getResources().getBoolean(R.bool.isTablet) {
    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
}
```

This will lock the orientation, only if it chooses the default resource file-  only if its smaller than a tablet.

Comment: it works but changing is not instant , another words when I open my app it waits for a sec and then goes to landscape , any idea why ?

Comment: Where are you putting the code?  Place it before you call setContentView().  Otherwise it could set the landscape view, then need to change it with the request to lock